# Send a file from a client to another in a C chat

Tags: c, sockets, chat

I am creating a chat in C (Should work on Ubuntu 16.04) based on the IRC protocol. I already create the client.c and the server.c. The chat is working ok and a client can send a message to the server and the server re-send the message to one or all clients. The problem is that I dont know how send a file from a client to another client.

It should be something like the client 1 send part of the file to the server and the server re-send it to the client 2 and so on. The problem is that I dont know how to do it because the server must continue attending the clients while it is sending and receiving the file. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select in the server main loop was all i need